# Saving multiple entries of 'contenteditable' in localstorage..?

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable

I'm trying to save more than one entry of contenteditable content into my localstorage for a Chrome extension. My current code saves just one contenteditable section fine, but when I try to add another Id of a seperate contenteditable section it either deletes all the saved information or doesn't do anything at all. I'm pretty novice in JS, so I hope I'm just making a simple mistake. 
 My html looks like this:

```
<div id = "content">
<div id= "tcontent" contenteditable="true" data-ph=" Make a note . . . "
style= "height: 300px; overflow: auto"></div>
```

```
<div id = "content2">
<div id= "tcontent2" contenteditable="true" data-ph= " Make a note . . . "
style= "height: 300px; overflow: auto"></div>
</div>
```

And this is my Javascript:

```
window.addEventListener('load', onLoad); function onLoad() {
checkEdits();
}
function checkEdits() {
    if(localStorage.userEdits!=null) {
        document.getElementById("tcontent").innerHTML +=     localStorage.userEdits;
}
};

document.onkeyup = function (e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    console.log(e.keyCode);
          saveEdits();


};
function saveEdits() {
var editElem = document.getElementById("tcontent");
var userVersion = editElem.innerHTML;
localStorage.userEdits = userVersion;
};
```

I've already tried just adding , ("tcontent2") to the JS with no avail. Also any variations of that, such as just repeating the vars with tcontent2.

```
window.addEventListener('load', onLoad);
function onLoad() {
checkEdits();
}
function checkEdits() {
if(localStorage.userEdits!=null) {
    document.getElementById("tcontent","tcontent2").innerHTML += localStorage.userEdits;
}
};

document.onkeyup = function (e) {
e = e || window.event;
console.log(e.keyCode);
      saveEdits();


};
function saveEdits() {
var editElem = document.getElementById("tcontent","tcontent2");
var userVersion = editElem.innerHTML;
localStorage.userEdits = userVersion; 
};
```

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: *"I've already tried just adding , ("tcontent2") to the JS, but that doesn't seem to work"* That should work just fine. Double-check it for simple typos, etc., and if you still have a problem, show us the code.

Comment: I might also note, 'tcontent2' is located within a checkbox, hopefully that doesn't effect localstorage.

Comment: this doesn't work for me:       window.addEventListener('load', onLoad);
function onLoad() {
 checkEdits();
}
function checkEdits() {
 if(localStorage.userEdits!=null) {
  document.getElementById("tcontent","tcontent2").innerHTML += localStorage.userEdits;
 }
};

document.onkeyup = function (e) {
 e = e || window.event;
 console.log(e.keyCode);
          saveEdits();      
 
};
function saveEdits() {
 var editElem = document.getElementById("tcontent","tcontent2");
 var userVersion = editElem.innerHTML;
 localStorage.userEdits = userVersion;
};

Comment: To improve the question, use the "edit" link under the question, rather than comments (you can see why, above :-) ).